# Have const variables in an object which is used in a vector container

Tags: c++

So I am trying to make snake clone.

I have made a BodyPiece class which has certain variables I would like to be const, as they should not change. This was not a problem when I simply created an instance of Bodypiece to test out. However I want to be able to add pieces as the snake grows so I made a vector body variable. As you can see from the code below:

In BodyPiece.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "D3DGraphics.h"
#include "Keyboard.h"
#include "Direction.h"

class BodyPiece
{
public:
    BodyPiece(int xPos, int yPos, Direction* dir);
    ~BodyPiece();
    void Draw(D3DGraphics& gfx);
    void UpdateDirection(KeyboardClient& kbd);
    void Move();
private:
    Direction* dir;
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
    int width = 5;
    int height = 5;
    int vx = 5;
    int vy = 5;
};
```

In Game.h file

BodyPiece vector body declared:

```
std::vector<BodyPiece> body;
```

In Game.cpp file

vector initialised in initialiser list.

```
body({ {400, 300, &d } })
```

If I make any variables in BodyPiece const, it will generate an error:

error C2582 'operator=' function is unavailable in class BodyPiece.

My questions here are:

What causes that? I have looked online and have a little bit of an idea but it really is only a little bit.

How can I have const variables, use a vector container(or another type of container if that will help, does not have to be vector) and keep the compiler happy? Or should I just completely change my approach?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but in the expression `body({ {400, 300, &d } })` that `&d` seems very suspect. What is `d`? Is it a local variable that will go out of scope? And if you do that in a loop, and `d` is defined outside the loop, then all pointers for all `BodyPiece` objects will be the same, all pointing to the same `d`.

Comment: A guess: try std::vector<const BodyPiece>? Inserting into a vector calls copy ctor, IIRC, though I don't know offhand what that means for const-ness.

Comment: @ Joachim Pileborg I have a direction class which I use to help move the piece around the screen. You can see in the constructor of BodyPiece, the Direction* dir variable. And in my Game file, I create an object of that class, and use it to initialise body. If that makes sense.. Not sure I am explaining myself very well

Comment: shouldn't those (constants?) weight,height be static?

Comment: Think about what you are asking your code to do.  If you make a member variable `const` then it can never be changed.  If the variable can never be changed then `operator =` would not be able to assign one object to the other.

Comment: Can you post your constructor code? Are you trying to make `xPos` `yPos` or `dir` const?

Comment: So an "easy" fix would be to overload the `operator=` and just assign the *non-const* values.

Comment: And why is it so important that they are `const`'s? If it's a matter of assigning them a value, do it in the constructor or, as @Exceptyon suggested and make them static, setting value by declaration.

Comment: While I posted an answer, I don't really can't match the error with the code you show. You say you have constant variables, but you *don't* have that in the class you show, all you have are member variables that have default initializers.

Comment: Which variables do you want to make `const`? How does line at which you get the error look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that if you don't have an assignment operator, then the compiler will generate one for you, that does simple shallow copying of the members. However, if you have actual `const` member variables (and not only default-initialized like yours) then those can't be copied and the compiler can't create an assignment operator.

The simple solution is to make the constants actual constants and also `static` so they are members of the *class* and not part of a single object:

```
class BodyPiece
{
    ...
    static int const width = 5;
    static int const height = 5;
};
```

The only drawback with this is that you need to actually *define* these member variables, in a single source file:

```
int const BodyPiece::width;
int const BodyPiece::height;
```

The other solution is to explicitly create an assignment operator that copies the data needed:

```
class BodyPiece
{
public:
    ...
    BodyPiece& operator=(BodyPiece const& other)
    {
        // Copy data from other to this
        xPos = other.xPos;
        ...
        return *this;
    }
    ...
};
```

Comment: Hmm... Ran some tests, and in VC you don't need the definition part. If it's a `const`, you define it in the class declaration.

Comment: @ClasG this is covered by the One Definition Rule. Such integral constants may be left without a definition as long as you don't try to do something that actually requires a unique definition (such as taking the variable's address).